# How to check if SSH (Remote Access) is turned on for OS X 10.7 account with no admin rights

Tags: ssh, osx-lion, admin

I have a program that needs to display an indicator of whether SSH (remote access) is turned on for the current user account.  We used to do this by calling "/sbin/service --test-if-configured-on ssh" and parsing the results, but service went away on OS X 10.7.  Now we're calling "/usr/sbin/systemsetup -getremotelogin" and parsing the results, however this only works if the account has admin rights.  Another possibility is to open an SSH connection to 127.0.0.1 in the background, however since I don't have access to the username and password, this will error out after a long timeout, so the indicator is not updated for a minute or two.

Does anyone know of a better alternative?  Thanks!

Harry